# How to pass $_FILES to remote server along with few $_POST data using Php Curl

Tags: php, post, curl

Below is the code for sending data from my client server to remote server:

```
$fields_string = "";
        $fields = array();
        $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
        $url = 'http://192.168.1.xx/proj_v6/upload_amax_data';
        if (isset($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])) {
            $filename  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
            $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $fields = array(
                          'file' =>
          '@'            . $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]
          . ';filename=' . $_FILES['files']['name'][0]
          . ';type='     . $_FILES['files']['type'][0]
                        );

        }
        $fields = array(
            'r_token' => urlencode(REMOTE_AUTH_TOKEN),
            'lname' => urlencode('$lname'),
            'fname' => urlencode('$first_name'),
            'title' => urlencode('$title'),
            'company' => urlencode('$institution'),
            'age' => urlencode('$age'),
            'email' => urlencode('$email'),
            'phone' => urlencode('$phone')
        );
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting the $_POST data in remote server but not the $_FILES data... tried some site but no luck...

IMPORTANT NOTE: How can i pass "$_FILES" along with "$_POST" data using php curl to remote server.

Comment: What does the `<form>` tag look like? Most often when `$_FILES` is empty but `$_POST` is populated, it is because the `<form>` is missing the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i am getting $_FILES in my php function in client from ajax submitted form using jquery file upload and i was able to print_r() the same to values... yes i have mentioned the multipart/form-data in my form though... the problem i think is with my curl

Comment: So the problem is not that `$_FILES` is empty in the original upload but rather that the files are not transmitted with curl? I misunderstood that.

Comment: Post the output from `print_r($fields)` and from `echo $fields_string;` so we can see what ends up in there. It appears you are overwriting `$fields` because you call `$fields = array(...)` twice. Perhaps you meant to append to the array rather than reset it.

Comment: @Micheal okay will check 2marrow hope to slove this 2marow

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes the issue was with the post field array... i have corrected it and now i am getting both $_POST and $_FILES in remote server now... thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])) {
            $filename  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
            $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $fields['image'] = '@'.$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]
          . ';filename=' . $_FILES['files']['name'][0]
          . ';type='     . $_FILES['files']['type'][0];
        }
```